# how to set color for a text without third party pkg

Tags: go, colors

I want some text to be colored red and green. if the `value < 0` then the color will be red and if the `value > 0` then color will be green:

```
if x < 0 {
    fmt.Println("This line will be Red")
} else {
    fmt.Println("This line will be Green")
}
```

I want to know how to do that with the standard library not with third party pkg.
How I can do that?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
if x < 0 {
    fmt.Println("\x1b[31;1m This line will be Red \x1b[0m")
} else {
    fmt.Println("\x1b[32;1m This line will be Green \x1b[0m")
}
```

You can play with the first number to change the color: `[31,32,33...]` and you always end with `\x1b[0m`.